# Cant remove specific React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-state, react-component

This is my `Add_Blog.js` file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function AddBlogs() {

const ADD = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>Topic</label>
            <input></input>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <button type="button" onClick={deleteContent} value={state.length}> Delete</button>
        </div>
    );
}
const [state, setState] = useState([<ADD key="first"></ADD>]);


const addblog = () => {
    setState([...state, <ADD key={state.length}></ADD>])
}


const deleteContent = (event, key) => {
    setState([...state, state.splice(event.target.value, 1)]);

}

return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Add Title</label>
                <input></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                {
                    state
                }

            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={addblog}>Add another topic</button>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="publish"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
);
}
export default AddBlogs;
```

My expectation from this code is to remove component left of delete button when I press that delete button. But when I press delete button it removes that component and every components below it.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are using the [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method wrong. It returns the deleted value.

You can change your deleteContent function like this:

```
const deleteContent = (event, key) => {
  let indexToRemove = Number(event.target.value);
  setState((prevState) => prevState.filter((elem, index) => index !== indexToRemove));
}
```

That will be enough for the program to work as expected